# Ansible regex_findall multiple strings

Tags: ios, regex, ansible, findall

Cisco IOS routers, doing a "dir", and I want to grab all file names with ".bin" in the name.

Example string:
Directory of flash0:/

```
1  -rw-    95890300  May 24 2015 11:27:22 +00:00  c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.153-3.M5.bin
2  -rw-    68569216   Feb 8 2019 20:15:26 +00:00  c3900e-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M10.bin
3  -rw-       46880  Oct 25 2017 19:08:56 +00:00  pdcamadeusrtra-cfg
4  -rw-         600   Feb 1 2019 19:36:44 +00:00  vlan.dat
```

260153344 bytes total (95637504 bytes free)

I've figured out how to pull "bin", but I can't figure out how to pull the whole filename (starting with " c", ending in "bin"), because I want to then use the values and delete unwanted files.

I'm new to programming, so the regex examples are a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
^[\w\W]+?(?=(c.*\.bin))\1$
```

- `^` - Start of string.
- `[\w\W]+?` - Match anything one or more time ( Lazy mode ).
- `(?=(c.*\.bin))` - Positive lookahead match c followed by anything followed by `\.bin` ( Group 1)
- `\1`  - Match group 1.
- `$` - End of string.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/6yXJBF/2/)

Comment: that works, but then only returns the last instance found:
ok: [10.35.91.200] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    binfiles:
    - c2800nm-adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin

Comment: @what do you mean ? did you checked you used proper flags ?

Comment: Here's the statement:
binfiles="{{ dir_response.stdout[0] | regex_findall('[\w\W]+?(?=(c.*\.bin))\1$') }}"

This is the result:
TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************
task path: /export/home/e130885/playbooks/ios-switch-upgrade/ios_clean_flash.yml:16
Monday 11 February 2019  11:31:47 -0600 (0:00:00.386)       0:00:03.037 ******* 
ok: [10.35.91.200] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    binfiles:
    - c2800nm-adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

Thank you!

Comment: And what does `"{{ dir_response.stdout[0] }}` by its onesie look like?

Comment: TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
Monday 11 February 2019  12:46:17 -0600 (0:00:02.752)       0:00:02.815 ******* 
ok: [10.35.91.200] => 
  msg:
  - |-
    1  -rw-    95890300  May 24 2015 11:27:22 +00:00  c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.153-3.M5.bin
        2  -rw-    68569216   Feb 8 2019 20:15:26 +00:00  c3900e-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M10.bin
        5  -rw-    67929600   Feb 8 2019 21:24:56 +00:00  c2800nm-adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin

Answer (score 0):

To match the filename that start with a `c` (or at the start of the string) you might use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)` to check what is on the left is not a non-whitespace character.

Then match either 1+ times not a whitespace character `\S+` or list in a character class `[\w.-]+` what the allowed characters are to match. After that match a dot `\.` followed by `bin`.

At the end you might use a word boundary `\b` to prevent `bin` being part of a larger word:

```
(?<!\S)[\w.-]+\.bin\b
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/LMBLFC/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Code Maniac!
Your code finds one instance, and I needed to find all. Using what you gave me plus messing around with some other examples, I found this to work:

binfiles="{{ dir_response.stdout[0] | regex_findall('\b(?=(c.*.bin))\b') }}"

Now I get this:
TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************
task path: /export/home/e130885/playbooks/ios-switch-upgrade/ios_clean_flash.yml:16
Tuesday 12 February 2019  08:29:58 -0600 (0:00:00.350)       0:00:03.028 ****** 
ok: [10.35.91.200] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    binfiles:
    - c2900-universalk9-mz.SPA.153-3.M5.bin
    - c3900e-universalk9-mz.SPA.151-4.M10.bin
    - c2800nm-adventerprisek9-mz.151-4.M12a.bin

Onto the next task of figuring out how to use each element. Thank you!